Cant install pods after installing react-native-firebase/firestore



MacBook-Air ios % pod install [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "nanopb":   In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
nanopb (< 2.30911.0, = 2.30910.0, >= 2.30908.0)   In Podfile:
RNFBFirestore (from ../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/firestore) was resolved to
19.1.1, which depends on
nanopb (< 2.30910.0, >= 2.30908.0) You have either:  * out-of-date source repos which you can update with pod repo update or with pod install --repo-update.  * changed the constraints of dependency nanopb inside your development pod RNFBFirestore.    You should run pod update nanopb to apply changes you've made.
*
Even after adding and updating all those things, xcode build will fail. idk how can I resolve and make a clean installation of firestore, please help

Did you tried the command pod repo update?

Please also indicate what version of Cocoapods is being used.


disable flipper

specify the version of nanopb by adding this:
pod 'nanopd', '< 2.30910.0'
in your target, then run:
pod install --repo-update

clean build and build the project again


if you are a bit confused with the podfile here is my
my podfile for reference:
# Resolve react_native_pods.rb with node to allow for hoisting
use_modular_headers!
$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
  'require.resolve(
    "react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb",
    {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
  )', __dir__]).strip

platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
prepare_react_native_project!

# If you are using a `react-native-flipper` your iOS build will fail when `NO_FLIPPER=1` is set.
# because `react-native-flipper` depends on (FlipperKit,...) that will be excluded
#
# To fix this you can also exclude `react-native-flipper` using a `react-native.config.js`
# ```js
# module.exports = {
#   dependencies: {
#     ...(process.env.NO_FLIPPER ? { 'react-native-flipper': { platforms: { ios: null } } } : {}),
# ```
flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'temp' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  pod 'nanopb', '< 2.30910.0'
  pod 'gRPC', '1.62.0'
  pod 'gRPC-Core', '1.62.0'
  
  # Add Firebase Pods with modular headers and enable bridged/compatibility mode
  pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
  
  flags = get_default_flags()
  use_frameworks! :linkage => :static

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line. 
#    :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'tempTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    # https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/packages/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb#L197-L202
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      config[:reactNativePath],
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
  end
end

I faced the same issue, I had to delete the derived data folder and re run the project.
